# How would you find the length of a side of a triangle where 2 sides are known and the length of a line in the middle is also known?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

How would you find the length of a side of a triangle where the other 2 side lengths are known and the length of a another line that meets at the same point is known?

I know there has to be an answer to this because if you take 3 sticks of different lengths and have them meet at a point, and then you angle the 3 sticks such that there other ends all lie on the same line, there is only one solutions. So assuming you know the lengths of the 3 sticks, how would you find the length of the line that they all lie on. (The picture may help)

[image]

Comment: A bisecting line needs to bisect something. What is that something?

Comment: Ow sorry. It doesn't bisect the triangle. It just meets at the same point as the other lines and goes through the triangle. See the picture.

Comment: I am transferring your image to this page.  This site prefers that users not make use of external file sites, as there is no guarantee the image will remain available indefinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with three concentric circles with radii of $ \ 1 \ , \ 1.5 \ , \ \text{and} \ 2 \ $ .  Choose a point on the innermost circle and another on the outermost and connect them with a line segment.  Rays from the common center of the circles to the intersection points of the first line segment with the three circles form the other three lines in your triangle.  The illustration below shows just two of the possibilities.  Were you to specify just one angle anywhere in your construction, the result *would* be unique (and would be solved by applying the Laws of Sines and of Cosines); otherwise, there is not enough information to answer your question.

[image]

Comment: Well drawn.  I was about to post a picture which pales greatly in comparison.  May I ask what program you used to draw this in?

Comment: This is from the Grapher utility in the Mac operating system.

Comment: Thanks for the graph. I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram shows that there are sometimes two possible solutions. The shorter side could meet the desired line at an angle of either less or more than $90^\circ$.

There are actually infinitely many solutions because the angle between the shorter sides could be varied before placing the longest side.

Comment: Thank You. I didn't realize there were 2 answers. How would you find them?

Comment: @JacobRichman: There are many more than two. =)

Comment: @JacobRichman: The question becomes interesting when you require an additional condition on the third line, like bisecting the angle or the opposite side.

Comment: Assuming that the lengths of the 2 sides and middle line are predefined, I don't think there would be an infinite amount of answers.

Comment: @JacobRichman: Just play with a ruler and pencil and see.

Comment: So, there's no mathematical way to find it?

Comment: @JacobRichman: If there are infinitely many solutions, what do you want to find? The whole set?

Comment: @Jacob and @ user21820 "the whole set" is actually rather easy to describe.  As per the triangle inequality, the remaining side length is between $1$ and $3$ (exclusive if you define a triangle as needing strictly positive area and linesegments not being allowed to overlap).  All values are indeed possible.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Yup correct, though it is a bit more work if you want the set of solution triangles and not just the length of the opposite side.